RST_STREAM closed stream unexpectedly in Gatling-grpc
Note: using this Gatling community plugin for gRPC, not the official one.
I have a sample code to setup a single UNARY grpc call in Gatling as below:
class grpcDemo extends Simulation {

  val grpcConf = grpc(managedChannelBuilder(target = s"grpcbin.test.k6.io:9000").usePlaintext())
                    .disableWarmUp
  val demoMessage = (session: io.gatling.core.session.Session) => {
    HelloRequest(
        greeting = Option[String]("name")
    )
  }
  val grpcCallDefine = grpc("Unary")
        .rpc(HelloServiceGrpc.METHOD_SAY_HELLO)
        .payload(demoMessage)
        .check(statusCode is Status.Code.OK)

  val scn = scenario("BasicSimulation") 
        .exec(grpcCallDefine)

  setUp(
    scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))
  ).protocols(grpcConf)
}

Here is my protobuf file, taken from k6 grpc endpoint grpcbin.test.k6.io:
syntax = "proto2";

package hello;

service HelloService {
  rpc SayHello(HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse);
  rpc LotsOfReplies(HelloRequest) returns (stream HelloResponse);
  rpc LotsOfGreetings(stream HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse);
  rpc BidiHello(stream HelloRequest) returns (stream HelloResponse);
}

message HelloRequest {
  optional string greeting = 1;
}

message HelloResponse {
  required string reply = 1;
}

Run a simple test, I then got this weird error:
Session:
Session(BasicSimulation,1,Map(gatling.grpc.channel -> ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper{delegate=ManagedChannelImpl{logId=1, target=grpcbin.test.k6.io:9000}}),OK,List(),io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry$$Lambda$442/0x000000900145fc20@2f066478,io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop@706a757e)
=========================
gRPC request:
headers=
grpc-accept-encoding: gzip
payload=
greeting: "name"

=========================
gRPC response:
status=
UNAVAILABLE, description: RST_STREAM closed stream. HTTP/2 error code: NO_ERROR

What could be causing this behavior?
Tested the same endpoint with Postman, it worked. Not sure why Gatling-grpc would fail.
Edit: As I add in a repeat(2), Gatling will be hanging and the 2nd request will not be executed.

Since you're using plain text, it should be easy to use wireshark to see how the requests from different tools differ.

@GeorgeLeung it seems like server is using some sort of reflection is there anyway I can workaround on this one ?
